# Is there Gentoo's "world" set analogue for rpm-based distributions?

Tags: fedora, gentoo, yum, rpm

I want to maintain my Fedora distribution clean and tidy.
So, I always want to have installed only required packages. The necessity of a top packages is determined by me and some minimal system set. All other installed packages must be required by the top ones. Everything else should be removed.

There are a "world" and "system" sets in a Gentoo, which provide such functionality.
Are there any plugins or solutions for rpm-based or yum-based systems like Fedora?

All solutions and workarounds are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

In Fedora you can install a minimal set, but that one is *very* minimal (just enough to install stuff and move around a bit). I suppose you really mean install just what you are using, and that will very much depend on you. What I do when I'm absolutely bored is to get a list of installed packages, and check if something doesn't sound familiar.

The package-cleanup command (from yum-utils) has options for finding leaves (packages that don't depend on others), go through them, "yum erase" what you don't need, rinse and repeat.

Your question made me remember a tool from aeons back... the rpmorphan package contains rpmusage, which gives you detailed data (can ask for packages which haven't been used in X days, and so on).